# Is "Why not more?" a correct question?

Tags: questions, negation

Is *Why not more?* correct, or should it be *Why no more?*
What does it mean, then?

> Why don't you want anymore of something?

Or the opposite:

> Why not having some more of something?

Comment: There are problems with both your paraphrases. _Any more_ is not usually written as one word (some people do write it as one word when it means _no longer_, eg "I don't go there anymore", but I don't think anybody would in a case like this). And _Why not having..._ is not idiomatic. _Why_ (unlike the other question words) can take a verb in the base form, but not the "-ing" form; so _Why not have more of something?_

Answer (score 0):

Note that neither of these phrases is a full sentence. Both are responses to something that has been stated. Exactly what they mean depends on the context, so one can only give examples of their possible use.

A: I'm afraid that I can only offer you less than you require.
B: Why not more?

So B is asking why it is not possible to obtain more of the product concerned.

A: No fuel supplies will be available from tomorrow.
B: Why no more?

Here B's response could mean either why will there be no further fuel supplies or why will they no longer be available.

It's a question of context.